# Rails: Override a template only during the execution of a specific generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've created a generator that inherits of `Rails::Generators::ScaffoldControllerGenerator`.

Rspec scaffolding generator is invoked by Rails' generator. I want to override one of its templates.

I've successfully put my new template in this folder: `lib/templates/rspec/scaffold/`.

However, now when I use Rails's generator my new template is used instead of Rspec' default one.

Is there a way to override a template only during the execution of a specific generator?